# Newly created label will not show GUI

Tags: c#, user-interface

I am having some issues making my label show up in the gui... any thoughts?

```
private void addNewExcerciseButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            int y = 305;
            int x= 61;

            string tempExcercise = excerciseTextBox.Text;
            excerciseTextBox.Clear();


           Label[] excerciseLabels = new Label[numExercises];



           for (int i = 0; i < numExercises; ++i)
           {
                excerciseLabels[i] = new Label();
                excerciseLabels[i].Text = ToString("{0}. {1}", i + 1, tempExcercise);;
                excerciseLabels[i].Location = new System.Drawing.Point(x, y);
                x += 10;
                y += 10;


                ++numExercises;
           }
}
```

thanks in advance.

numExercises is global.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to add each new Label to the collection of Controls contained by a visible Control (such as your Form). You're creating and setting them up, but they aren't part of the GUI yet until they're in the control hierarchy.

Add the following line after setting the location of the label:

```
this.Controls.Add(exerciseLabels[i]);
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to add the label to the GUI:

```
this.Controls.Add(excersizeLabels[i]);
```

As a side note, there is no point in using an array.

Comment: I will be creating over 20+ labels so I made an array to do so.

Comment: Well, I'd disagree that there's no point in an array, but you are correct that he could define a List and set the initial capacity and get pretty much the same performance.

Comment: I often keep controls with common functionality or that I want to perform similar actions on in collections. Makes them easier to get than iterating the full Controls hierarchy especially if the controls are at different levels of that hierarchy.

Comment: If performance is the same... does it just come down to preference? Perhaps a list would be much easier to implement.

Comment: A List gives you the primary advantage of being resizable, so instead of defining the size of the collection up front (and having to know that value) you can just create an empty list and add to it until you're done. But, there's a cost to be paid for that; the List uses arrays behind the scenes, and when it runs out of room it must create a larger array, and this will happen several times as you add to it (the array will double in size each time it must be resized, which also creates unused capacity). Specifying an initial capacity, much like you have to do with the array, mitigates that.

Comment: I gotcha. I'll switch it all to a list. Thank you for the info.